# Existing Styles are broken after installing the ngx bootstrap

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, primeng, ngx-bootstrap

[image]after installing the ngx bootstrap in my existing application some of the styles are automatically changed without applying any classes like below,

we have a labels in form tag for that labels some bootstart classes automatically added how to prevent this auto applying styles ?

i tried to change viewEncapsulation none but its not working

```
<form [formGroup]="reportDataForm">
    <div class="ui-g-4">
         <label for="name">Organization Name</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't think you can achieve it because the style is applied to the tag name. You have to override it with your custom style

Comment: yes but same like this many places it got applied this styles so i want to change in all the places is difficult so looking for better option

Comment: The one in screenshot is from bootstrap, not from ngx-bs. I can't see a workaround here other than deleting stylings for HTML tags in bs/dist/

Comment: ngx bootstrap is dependent to bootstrap styles, if i didnot added this styles ngx wont work.